# WaitHandle.WaitOne returns true in IDE debug but not in Immediate Window

Tags: c#, waithandle

I can do this in my code I'm stepping though..

```
01 // In another sub
02 EventWaitHandle waitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "MyTestHandleName");
03
04 // In the current code block I'm debugging
05 bool retVal = false;
06 retVal = waitHandle.WaitOne(1000);
07 if (retVal) { }
```

Then I put brakes on line 06 and 07.  At line 06 retVal is the default value of FALSE.  In the Immediate Window I run `waitHandle.WaitOne(1000)` and it returns FALSE.

Then I press F10 and it finishes running line 06, then I check the value of retVal and see it's TRUE.  I then run `waitHandle.WaitOne(1000)` in the Immediate Window again and it still returns FALSE.

Question: Why is the Immediate Window returning a different value then the actual IDE during debug?

Comment: EventResetMode.AutoReset, that means it is automatically reset when you stepped past the Wait() call.  EventResetMode.ManualReset is the other option, it would then work as you expected.

Comment: Should I delete this question if in the end the mistake was mine (I was calling the Set method and did not know it)?  I feel like my question was leading everyone down the wrong path on what was happening to me.

Answer (score 1):

The immediate window is not a magical tool that can freeze time. It only executes the statements you enter, so what you do is equivalent to calling `WaitOne` twice. If the first call is successful, as this `WaitHandle` is `AutoReset`, the second call will naturally fail unless you release it.

[image: Result false]

[image: Result true]

Comment: @ArvoBowen I've added two pictures. If the WaitHandle is signaled, WaitOne will return true in the  immediate window.

Comment: Thanks for that!  Helps out a bunch...  But I'm not seeing that on my side.  I see that last image as FALSE and FALSE again.  Same situation though!  So for some reason mine is not working the same way.  On the first image does RESULT = true/false?  Mine = true while showing false in the second image (second false).

Comment: Just to be clear, if I NEVER called the Set method, should WaitOne ever return true?  Because I don't have a Set method being called anywhere.

Comment: Never mind!  I'm a dumb ass.  I found my issue, I was indeed calling that SET method after all..  It was hiding deep in the code and a quick find uncovered it.  Now everything is working as expected.